# Adding additional columns to my Oracle SQL result

Tags: oracle

I have a SQL query built that returns a singular column of figures. Sample is shown below. I need to enhance this in a singular query and retrieve a 2nd set of figures using similar filters/parameters (instead of status=E I'd look for category=E). This query has gotten fairly complex for my knowledge though and I'm a bit stumped on how to approach adding this additional SELECT statement to get a 2nd column. Appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

[image]

```sql
SELECT Count(eqnbr) EQUIP, 
       imp_exp, 
       'TITLE'      TITLE 
FROM  (SELECT cy.container                       EQNbr, 
              cy.location_position               "POS", 
              Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 1) Row_Nbr, 
              CASE 
                WHEN Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 3) IN ( 
                     'M01', 'N03', 'N04', 'N05', 
                     'N06', 'N07', 'N08', 'N09' ) THEN 
                'Rail' 
                WHEN Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 1) IN ( 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 
                                                             'K', 'L', 'M', 'P', 
                                                             'R', 'S' ) THEN 
                'Locals' 
                WHEN Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 1) IN ( 'B', 'D' ) THEN 
                'Export' 
                ELSE Concat ('Row ', Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 1)) 
              END                                IMP_EXP 
       FROM   current_yard cy 
       WHERE  eq_class = 'CTR' 
              AND location_position NOT LIKE 'CT%' 
              AND using_line NOT IN ( 'TEST', 'UNK', 'TST', 'B125', 
                                      'BO77', 'BR75' ) 
              AND using_line IS NOT NULL 
              AND ( container NOT LIKE 'TEST%' 
                     OR container NOT LIKE 'KENT%' ) 
              AND Length(container) >= 10 
              AND status = 'E' 
              AND Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 1) NOT IN 
                  ( '1', '2', '3', '4', 
                    '5', '6', '7', '8', 
                    '9', '0', 'A', 'C', 
                    'E', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X' )) a 
GROUP  BY imp_exp 
ORDER  BY 2 ASC
```

Comment: I'm confused by your description.  But wouldn't you be double counting `Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 3) = 'M01'` for Rail and `Substr(cy.location_position, 1, 1) = 'M'` for Locals?

Comment: I thought it worked like a case statement where the first match wins, so to speak.